# Most frequently occuring number (mode) in a list - want to get only the highest value

Tags: javascript, mode

I'm trying to get whatever number is the most frequently occuring number in an array, so for an array containing 1,2,10,5,1 the result should be 1. The code I wrote returns me the frequency for each number, so 1 occurs twice, 2 occurs once, 10 occurs once etc. Any suggestions how I can fix my result?

```
function mode(arr) {
var uniqNum = {};
var numCounter = function(num, counter) {
  if(!uniqNum.hasOwnProperty(num)) {
    uniqNum[num] = 1;
  } else {
    uniqNum[num] ++;
    }
};
arr.forEach(numCounter);
return uniqNum;
}
```

Comment: Another variable and an if statement to keep track of which number is in the lead? Except, what do you want to do if two or more numbers have the same frequency?

Comment: If two or more numbers have the hightest frequency, I'd want each number, so [1,2,1,2,3,4], I would want my result to be 1,2.

Answer (score 1):

First we want to make an array where we count the number of occurrences of a certain value *up to that point*.

Then we use the reduce function to return an array of values read from the original array for the indexes whose values have the current max appearances. We redefine max and empty the final output array of modes (if new max is established) as we go along. We want this to be a collection in case there is a tie for maximum appearances.

Additional advantage of the below is that it doesn't require  sort which is more expensive o(nlog n) and keeps the time complexity down to just linear. I also wanted to keep the functions used down to only two (map and reduce) as it is all that is need in this case.

edit: fixed a major bug uniqNum[e] += 1 instead of uniqNum[e] + 1 which went unnoticed as my initial case array was still returning expected result. Also made the syntax more concise in favor of more comments.

```js
var arr = [1,2,10,5,1,5,2,2,5,3,3];
//global max to keep track of which value has most appearances.
var max = -1;
var uniqNum = {};

     var modeArray = arr.map(function(e) {
     //create array that counts appearances of the value up to that point starting from beginning of the input arr array.       
      if(!uniqNum.hasOwnProperty(e)) {
              uniqNum[e] = 1;
              return 1;
         } else {
              return uniqNum[e] += 1;
          }
        //reduce the above appearance count array into an array that only contains values of the modes
       }).reduce(function (modes, e1, i) {
              //if max gets beaten then redefine the mode array to only include the new max appearance value.
              if(e1 > max){
                  //redefining max
                  max = e1;
                  //returning only the new max element
                  return [arr[i]];
                  //if its a tie we still want to include the current value but we don't want to empty the array.
                }else if(e1 == max){
                   //append onto the modes array the co-max value
                   return[...modes, arr[i]];
                }
                return modes;
        },[]);

alert(modeArray);
```

Here is a test you can run of my solution against @acontell. In my browser (Chrome with V8) my solution was around three-four times faster for arrays with large number of repeating values and even bigger advantage with distributions with lower number of repeating values. @acontell 's is a cleaner looking solution for sure, but definitely not faster in execution.

```js
    var arr = [];
    for(var i=0; i < 100000; i++){
            arr.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 1)) + 1);
        
    }
    
    console.time("test"); 
    test();



    function test(){

    var max = -1;
    var uniqNum = {};

         var modeArray = arr.map(function(e) {
         //create array that counts appearances of the value up to that point starting from beginning of the input arr array.       
          if(!uniqNum.hasOwnProperty(e)) {
                  uniqNum[e] = 1;
                  return 1;
             } else {
                  return uniqNum[e] += 1;
              }
            //reduce the above appearance count array into an array that only contains values of the modes
           }).reduce(function (modes, e1, i) {
                  //if max gets beaten then redefine the mode array to only include the new max appearance value.
                  if(e1 > max){
                      //redefining max
                      max = e1;
                      //returning only the new max element
                      return [arr[i]];
                      //if its a tie we still want to include the current value but we don't want to empty the array.
                    }else if(e1 == max){
                       //append onto the modes array the co-max value
                        modes.push(arr[i])    
                       return modes;
                    }
                    return modes;
            },[]);


    }

    console.timeEnd("test");

console.time("test1");
test1();

function test1 () {
  var freq = [],
        uniqNum = {},
        i;
      arr.forEach(function(num) {
        uniqNum[num] = i = (uniqNum[num] || 0) + 1;
        freq[i] = (freq[i] || []).concat(num);
      });
      return freq[freq.length - 1];

}

console.timeEnd("test1");
```

Comment: You deserve an upvote, well done! I'll try to check it tomorrow (no time today).

Answer (score 1):

I've kept your code unchanged and added some extra statements. Here is the demo: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/rrdxRo

```js
function mode(arr) {
  var uniqNum = {};

  var numCounter = function(num, counter) {
    if(!uniqNum.hasOwnProperty(num)) {
      uniqNum[num] = 1;
    } else {
      uniqNum[num] ++;
    }
  };

  arr.forEach(numCounter);

  return Object.keys(uniqNum)
    .sort((a,b) => uniqNum[b] - uniqNum[a])                       // sort by frequency
    .filter((val,ind,array) => uniqNum[array[0]] == uniqNum[val]) // leave only most frequent
    .map(val => Number(val));                                     // convert text to number
}

console.log(  JSON.stringify(mode([3,3,2,4,4]))  ) // [3,4]
console.log(  JSON.stringify(mode([2,4,3,3]))    ) // [3]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be done only with a little modification to your `forEach` loop and the assistance of another auxiliary data structure:

```
function mode(arr) {
    var freq = [], uniqNum = {}, i;
    arr.forEach(function (num) {
        uniqNum[num] = i = (uniqNum[num] || 0) + 1;
        freq[i] = (freq[i] || []).concat(num);
    });
    return freq[freq.length - 1];
}

console.log(mode([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 1, 6]));
```

With only one iteration over all the elements of the array we can gather enough information to print out the result:

1. `uniqNum` is the set you created to gather info about the element's frequency.
2. `freq` will be an array which last element will contain an array with the elements of higher frequency.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ckj7vhjq/). Hope it helps.

Comment: clever answer :-)

Comment: Thanks @LucasKot-Zaniewski and upvote would be greatly appreciated! Cheers!

Comment: although the 2d frequency array will grow large rather quickly (depending on the occurrences) so there is definitely a significant tradeoff considering the possibility of larger input arrays. Gave you an upvote but its something worth considering. Plus you are not saving *that* much time by iterating once instead of twice. Solution does look extremely neat though.

Comment: Thanks @LucasKot-Zaniewski! Arrays and objects in JS are really cheap.In fact, an array is no less than an object with an additional set of properties inherited by Array.prototype. If the initial array were big, iterating over all of its elements once would definetely be quicker than having to do it twice (some answers even sort the array...). I think the space problem should be considered as well, but from my point of view, a time problem would come up sooner (the array should have to be huge to encounter a space problem and probably some of the proposed algorithms would take ages to finish).

Comment: Totally agree as to the unnecessary sorting. I tested your solution against mine and think you are underestimating the memory overhead of your data structure. I don't think it works as efficiently as you think. But if you don't believe me check the test in my updated answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried as an exercise to solve this with native js functions.

```
var arr = [1,2,10,5,1];

// groupBy number
var x = arr.reduce(
    function(ac, cur){ 
         ac[cur]?(ac[cur] = ac[cur] + 1):ac[cur] = 1; 
         return ac;
     }, {}
);

// sort in order of frequencies
var res = Object.keys(x).sort(
    function(a,b){ return x[a] < x[b]}
);

res[0] has the most frequent element
```

Comment: Your line `ac[cur]?(ac[cur] = ac[cur] + 1):ac[cur] = 1; ` can be sortened to `ac[cur] = (ac[cur] || 0) + 1;`